# How not to close process, started from ubuntu terminal, and continue to execute another commands from terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I'm not advanced linux user. I use ubuntu.

When I start any process from terminal, for example firefox, I type in:

firefox

The process starts and then I need to write another commands in terminal. For example, I want to change directory, but I can't do it, because firefox is started. And I don't want to close it, but  want to enable terminal.

Sorry if my explanation is not clear, I do not know english well.

Comment: In addition of other answers (for starting `firefox &`) you might perhaps be interested in http://linux.die.net/man/1/batch & http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup & http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start the process in the backgroun with

```
firefox &
```

If you start it with

```
firefox
```

it will be in the foreground and you can move it to the background with ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>*** (this will put it in the background but the process will freez until you use bg command) then you must execute

```
bg 1
```

where 1 is the job id. You can see the job id with command

```
jobs
```

If you need to return the process to the foreground you must use

```
fg 1
```

where 1 is the job id.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this here:

```
firefox &
```

drops it to the background.

Also check out the commands `disown`, `nohup` and `fg`.

Answer (score 3):

If your command has already started, you can use ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>*** to send a suspend signal to the running process. Then you can use the `bg` command (passing in `%1` to symbolize the first process on the job list) and that will turn it into a background process, as if you had used the `&` in the original command.

Answer (score 1):

If you end your command line with `&`, the program will run in the background and you will be able to use the terminal for other commands. Example: `firefox &`.

Answer (score 0):

To run any command in background just put & at the end of command